# Distance from point to two neighboring points (both directions) in on polyline of pipe system

Tags: point, distance, network

I need to find the distance of a valve to the two neighboring corners in a piping system.

I have the following shp files:

-Nodes for the valves
-Nodes for the corners
-line layer file of the piping system.

I need to compute the distance from a valve node, to the two neighboring corners. So the search should be in both directions. I looked at options to make a network of the piping system and find the distance from the valve to the two nearest neighbors, but the problem is the direction restriction.

If one searches for the nearest two neighbors the result could be two corners at the one end of the pipe that were the closed, instead of one corner at one side of the pipe and the other corner at the other side of the pipe.

I added a picture to illustrate the problem. I should get the distances from the valve to corners 1 and 2. But with the nearest neighbor I would get the distance to corner 1 and 3.

[image]

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Which GIS software are you using? Where do you want to store the distances?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.